# How we work an svc file together?

Tags: wcf, web-services, tfs, partial-classes

We works, two developer on a wcf service project together. But we want to work different methods, seperately at the same time on a svc file and interface ?

How can we do it? Are partial classes help to us?

Comment: What is the problem working on the same file? Your source control should be easily able to auto-merge it if you work on different functions.

Comment: Our corporate policies doesn't allow to work a file at the same time.

Comment: Then either don't or change the company policy. I don't think there are technical solutions to a company policy. Maybe the policy makes sense, you may want to ask what the suggested alternative to the forbidden way is.

Comment: No i don't think so. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of solution.

1.You can create `development branch` , but for the end your must merge (`Isolation risk is made for big parallel update` )

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181423(v=vs.110).aspx

Search before about best practise : Trunc X.Y.Z / Service Pack / Fix / Release

1. You can also set `partial` modifier on your `proxy class` generated by `svcutil` `(Reference.cs)`
   with this solution, interface must contain all methods
2. You can also work without theses solution, just create your full layer (With interface and empty methods), check in on tfs and get lastest on another machine, after that begin specific devs for everyone